# Rotating 2d in WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

How to rotate and scale 2d objects in WebGL?
I think we will make changes in the "vPostion" part, but I could not set it fully.
javascript:

```
function render() {

    tMatrix = mat4();
    tMatrix = translate(0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: Why do you set `gl_Position.z = 0.0;` and  `gl_Position.w = 1.0;`?

Comment: for try something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a transformationMatrix, so just rotate this matrix.

First write a function to rotate a matrix, m, such as follows:

```
  function rotateX(m, angle) {
        var c = Math.cos(angle);
        var s = Math.sin(angle);
        var mv1 = m[1], mv5 = m[5], mv9 = m[9];

        m[1] = m[1]*c-m[2]*s;
        m[5] = m[5]*c-m[6]*s;
        m[9] = m[9]*c-m[10]*s;

        m[2] = m[2]*c+mv1*s;
        m[6] = m[6]*c+mv5*s;
        m[10] = m[10]*c+mv9*s;
     }
```

Scale first (you aren't doing any scaling currently),
Translate second,
Rotate third.

So your code should look like this:

```
transformationMatrix = mat4();
scale(transformationMatrix, 1, 1, 1);
rotateX(transformationMatrix, Math.PI/4);
translate(transformationMatrix, xPos, yPos, zPos);
```

You may also see other coders write (depending on their setup):

```
modelMatrix.scale(1,1,1).rotateX(Math.PI/4).translate(xPos,yPos,zPos);
```

Sources:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webgl/webgl_cube_rotation.htm
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16719/what-is-the-correct-order-to-multiply-scale-rotation-and-translation-matrices-f